# Cant update IEnumerable iterator variable

Tags: c#, .net

I'm stuck with next behaviour:

```
var contracts = result.Select(this.Map);
foreach (var contract in contracts) {
    contract.Id = 1;
}

return contracts;
```

After loop `contract.id` were not updated and still have initial value.

`var contracts = result.Select(this.Map).ToList();` solved my problem, but i can't figure out why couldn't I update properties of iterating variable?

Comment: Recommendation in these cases: Don't use `var`, use the explicit type.

Comment: @ytoledano That's advice that would generally be given when the person didn't realize their variable was the type that it actually is.  The title of their question makes it clear that they know the type is an `IEnumerable`, which it is.  If they thought it was something that it wasn't, that'd be an indication that `var` was biting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remember that **the results of a LINQ query is an object representing the query, not the results of that query**.  `contracts` is an object that, when iterated, will perform a mapping of each object in the underlying collection to a new object.  Each time it is iterated, it performs the mapping again.

In your case you're iterating the source collection, performing the mapping, editing those objects, *throwing those objects on the floor*, iterating the collection again, performing the mapping again, and then looking at those objects, so of course the edits you made aren't seen.

When you call `ToList` you're now no longer storing a query, but rather *the results of that query*, and edits to the items in that collection are observed, because you're looking at *the same items* in subsequent iterations.